# avro - schema for logicalType

Tags: avro

I am trying to learn avro and have a question in schema.

Some documents say

```
{
      "name": "userid",
       "type" : "string",
       "logicalType" : "uuid"
},
```

And some say

```
{
  "name": "userid",
  "type" : {
    "type" : "string",
    "logicalType" : "uuid"
  }
},
```

Which one is right? Or are they same?

Thank you!

Comment: I originally thought both, but now I think maybe just the second one is correct.

Answer (score 5):

I ran variants of your schemas with the [avro tools "random" command](https://avro.apache.org/releases.html#Download) ( aliased as `avro` below). It tries to generate a random value for a schema.

A schema with just this type using the nested type syntax to specify `logicalType` is rejected:

> `avro random --schema '{ "name": "userid", "type" : { "type": "string", "logicalType" : "uuid" } }' -`
>
> [...] No type: {"name":"userid","type":{"type":"string","logicalType":"uuid"}}

However, it works when putting the `logicalType` next to `type`:

> `avro random --schema ' { "type" : "string", "logicalType" : "uuid" }' -`
>
> [...] Objavro.schemaL{"type":"string","logicalType":"uuid"}avro.codecdeflate}�j�U�.�\�o���

Now, when we use it in a record, we get a warning when putting `logicalType` next to type:

> `avro random --schema '{ "type": "record", "fields": [ { "type" : "string", "logicalType" : "uuid", "name": "f"} ] , "name": "rec"}' -`
>
> [...] WARN avro.Schema: Ignored the rec.f.logicalType property ("uuid"). It should probably be nested inside the "type" for the field.
> Objavro.schema�{"type":"record","name":"rec","fields":[{"name":"f","type":"string","logicalType":"uuid"}]}avro.codecdeflate��w�9�9�n�s�

The nested syntax is accepted without a warning:

> `avro random --schema '{ "type": "record", "fields": [ { "type" : { "type": "string", "logicalType" : "uuid" } , "name": "f"} ] , "name": "rec"}' -`
>
> �w<��qcord","name":"rec","fields":[{"name":"f","type":{"type":"string","logicalType":"uuid"}}]}avro.codecdeflate8��t

Further if we look at logicaltypes inside arrays:

> `avro random --count 1 --schema ' { "type": "array", "items": { "type" : "string", "logicalType" : "uuid" , "name": "f"} , "name": "farr" } ' -`
>
> [... random bits]

While the nested version fails:

> `avro random --count 1 --schema ' { "type": "array", "items": {"type": { "type" : "string", "logicalType" : "uuid" , "name": "f"} } , "name": "farr" } ' -`
>
> [...] No type: {"type":{"type":"string","logicalType":"uuid","name":"f"}}

It appears that if a logicalType is a type of a field in a record, you need to use the nested syntax.
Otherwise you need to use non-nested syntax.